# make a dictionary from two arrays such that values of first array shows indices of second array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have two arrays:

```
a = array([0,    5,   10,   14, 20])
b = array([42, 41, 11, 22, 33, 10, 22,  2, 45,  3,  9, 10,  1,  3, 45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8])
```

Values of `a` are indices of `b` and I want to map `a` and `b` as a dictionary whose `keys` are indices of `a` and values are from `b`. First key of dictionary takes first 5 values of `b` , and second key takes next 5 values, third key takes next 4 values and fourth key takes next 6 values and this is inferred by subtracting two consecutive values of `a`.

Output should be like:

```
dict = {0: [42, 41, 11, 22, 33],
        1: [10, 22,  2, 45,  3] , 
        2: [9, 10,  1,  3], 
        3: [45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8]}
```

The actual size of `a` and `b` is in thousands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this by a dictionary comprehension, looping over the `a` list, indexing the `b` list by the values in `a`

```py
a = [0,  5,   10,   14, 20]
b = [42, 41, 11, 22, 33, 10, 22,  2, 45,  3,  9, 10,  1,  3, 45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8]

dct = {i: b[a[i]:a[i+1]] for i in range(len(a)-1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `numpy.array_split`  (I see you're using `array()`):

```py
x = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(np.array_split(b, a)[1:-1])}
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
{0: array([42, 41, 11, 22, 33]), 
 1: array([10, 22,  2, 45,  3]), 
 2: array([ 9, 10,  1,  3]), 
 3: array([45,  1,  4,  2,  9,  8])}
```

Comment: This is a cool solution. what does the `[1:-1]` do?

Comment: @oskros It will cut the result of `np.array_split` of first/last element (they are empty arrays).

Comment: Right, but why are they empty was perhaps my question :)

Comment: @oskros They're empty because the `a` list contains first and last index into the array `b` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy-array-split)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
a = [0, 5, 10, 14, 20]
b = [42, 41, 11, 22, 33, 10, 22,  2, 45,  3,  9, 10,  1,  3, 45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8]
dictn = {}
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    dictn[i] = b[a[i]:a[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a =[0,    5,   10,   14, 20]
b = [42, 41, 11, 22, 33, 10, 22,  2, 45,  3,  9, 10,  1,  3, 45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8]

d = {}

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    x = []
    for j in range(a[i+1] - a[i]):
        x.append(b.pop(0))
    d[int(i)] = x
print(d)
```

Comment: While that may answer the question it would be good if you also add some explanation to your answer, for example how the code works etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for your status

```
a = [0,    5,   10,   14]
b = [42, 41, 11, 22, 33, 10, 22,  2, 45,  3,  9, 10,  1,  3, 45,  1,  4, 2,  9,  8]
dict={}
/* num : Number of values in one key */
num=5
/* x: its for loop */
x=0
list=[]
for i in a:
    # check len of b to handle error out of list
    if x==len(b):
        break
    while x < num+1:
        list.append(b[x])
        dict[i]=list
        x = x + 1
        if num == x:
            num = num + 5
            list=[]
            break
print(dict)
```